# How to expose data to SSE from a @Tailable query in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, reactive

After reading the docs of `@Tailable` of Spring Data MongoDB, I think it is good to use it for message notifications.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class ServerApplication {

    @Bean
    fun runner(template: ReactiveMongoTemplate) = CommandLineRunner {
        println("running CommandLineRunner...")
        template.executeCommand("{\"convertToCapped\": \"messages\", size: 100000}");
    }

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<ServerApplication>(*args)
    }

}

---------


@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = ["messages"])
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:4200"])
class MessageController(private val messages: MessageRepository) {

    @PostMapping
    fun hello(p: String) =
            this.messages.save(Message(body = p, sentAt = Instant.now())).log().then()

    @GetMapping(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
    fun messageStream(): Flux<Message> = this.messages.getMessagesBy().log()
}


-----------



interface MessageRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<Message, String> {
    @Tailable
    fun getMessagesBy(): Flux<Message>
}


------------


@Document(collection = "messages")
data class Message(@Id var id: String? = null, var body: String, var sentAt: Instant = Instant.now())
```

<del>How to implement it?</del>

Done it by myself, check my [solution](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-sse-sample).

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue myself, check the [sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-sse-sample).

Also, [published a post](https://medium.com/@hantsy/building-a-chat-application-with-angular-and-spring-reactive-sse-c0fdddcd7d70) on medium to demonstrate how to use it a SPA client written in Angular.